java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.ResultSet.next()" because "schemas" is null in Liquibase maven liquibase:diff
I try to use mvn liquibase:diff on Hibernate entities and mysql database. Build fails on strange exception :  Cannot invoke "java.sql.ResultSet.next()" because "schemas" is null. My liquibase.properties:
driver:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
changeLogFile:src/main/resources/db/changelog/dbchangelog.xml
url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase
defaultSchemaName:liquibase
username:liquibase
password:liquibase
hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
referenceUrl:hibernate:org.heller.liqibase.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
referenceDefaultSchema:hibernate

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.heller.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>liquibase</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.27.0</liquibase.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate6.version>4.27.0</liquibase-hibernate6.version>
        <hibernate6.version>6.1.5.Final</hibernate6.version>
        <javassist.version>3.24.0-GA</javassist.version>
        <validation-api.version>3.0.2</validation-api.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.27.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.0.33</version>
                    </dependency>
                       <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate6.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>

Error in commandline:
https://pastebin.com/YR2svL6K
Can someone give me a poit how to solve this issue?

Do you understand what null is?

Does this answer your question? What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?

Of course I know what is Nullpointer, but your question is no sence. There was Exception in liquibase run, which comes from non-valid  liquibase.properties. It is fixed now.

Problem was in liquibase.properties. This example may works:
driver:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#changeLogFile:src/main/resources/db/changelog/dbchangelog.xml
url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liquibase
liquibaseSchemaName:liquibase
username:liquibase
password:liquibase
hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
referenceUrl:hibernate:spring:org.heller.liqibase.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
referenceDefaultSchema:hibernate

Here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.heller.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>liquibase</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.27.0</liquibase.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate6.version>4.27.0</liquibase-hibernate6.version>
        <hibernate6.version>6.1.5.Final</hibernate6.version>
        <javassist.version>3.24.0-GA</javassist.version>
        <validation-api.version>3.0.2</validation-api.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.27.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/dbchangelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>
                        src/main/resources/updates/${maven.build.timestamp}-changeLog.xml
                    </diffChangeLogFile>
                    <logging>debug</logging>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.0.33</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate6.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>


For anyone still struggle with this, below is the configuration that worked for me. The key was to add the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency under the liquibase-maven-plugin plugin.
Notice that liquibase.version is 4.27.0 and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.version is 3.2.5 (same as the version of the parent of Spring Boot project), hibernate-validator.version is 8.0.1.Final
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <searchPath>src/main/resources/liquibase/config</searchPath>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

